# Why can't C# infer the type of a DataTable Row

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-4.5, c#-6.0

I am trying to iterate over a DataTable and get the values from a particular column. So far I just have the Skeleton of the for loop.

```
foreach (var row in currentTable.Rows)
{
   var valueAtCurrentRow = row[0];
}
```

This does not work as I expected. I get an compiler error when trying to do `row[0]`, with the message: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Object". But `row` should not be an object, it is a `DataRow`.

To fix this I changed the foreach loop to the following:

```
foreach (DataRow row in currentTable.Rows)
{
   var valueAtCurrentRow = row[0];
}
```

Why is this necessary? Why can't C# infer the type of `row` as it would if I was trying to iterate over a `string[]` for example?

Comment: It looks like it's because the ```Rows``` property exposes a ```DataRowCollection```, which is IEnumerable, but not IEnumerable<DataRow> which means that enumerating it is the same as enumerating over a collection of ```object```, which means a cast is necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why can't C# infer the type of row as it would if I was trying to iterate over a string[] for example?

TL;DR: `DataTable` predates generics :(

[`DataTable.Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataTable_Rows) is declared to return [`DataRowCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=netframework-4.7.1), which derives from [`InternalDataCollectionBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase?view=netframework-4.7.1). That implements the non-generic `ICollection` interface, which means that the compiler can't infer the type of `row` beyond just `object`.

This isn't specific to `DataTable` - any time you have something that only implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` (and doesn't have a more specific `GetEnumerator` method for the compiler to use), the inferred iteration element type is just `object`. When you specify an explicit type for the variable in the `foreach` loop, the compiler silently inserts a cast for you.

I'd keep the change exactly as you've got it, but an alternative would be to use the `Cast` LINQ method:

```
foreach (var row in currentTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
   var valueAtCurrentRow = row[0];
}
```

Comment: And that's why `DataTable` is mostly deprecated... when you can use `DataTable<T>`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Unfortunately I am working on a legacy system, I have no choice but to use what is already in place.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've never heard of `DataTable<T>` and googling does not reveal anything, either. Can you give me a link of what you are talking about?

Comment: @UweKeim Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets), it's `DataSet<T>`

Comment: Before reading this i used the  OfType<T>  instead of casting using Cast , mostly on  DataGridView.Rows  or similarities when i needed to iterate

Answer (score 9):

The `Rows` property of the `DataTable` is an object of type `DataRowCollection`.

`DataRowCollection` itself inherits from `InternalDataCollectionBase` which implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`.

The data type contained in these collections isn't any further specified than `Object` thus it can't be inferred to the `DataRow` class.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference.

Answer (score -2):

Reason for it is Rows is `DataRowCollection` which is `IEnumerable` instead of  `IEnumerable<T>`, where T is DataRow.

Comment: Needs revision, doesn't make sense. Typo in IEnumberable ?

Comment: sorry typo from my end < T > was not displaying